# Iterate over a list replacing property values

Tags: c#

How would I iterate through a list replacing each property name with its value?

Below is what I have so far, could be way off here:-

```
public static string ReplaceText(List<Shared> list, string html)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in list.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            html = html.Replace("list property name", "list property value");
        }....
```

Comment: And what is your problem!??

Comment: replacing "list property name" and "list property value" with the data from the list is my problem

Comment: You would probably be better off using an existing templating library, e.g. https://github.com/rexm/Handlebars.Net or RazorEngine.

Comment: For starters, I presume you're not interested in properties of the generic List<T> type, but rather the properties of the Shared type, yes? In that regard, you'll need to start by enumerating through the Shared objects and then enumerating through the properties of each Shared object. This whole question seems very premature as you don't even have a working idea yet.

Comment: Also, did you mean to iterate through the list or through the properties of the list object? As it stands you may as well pass `object` rather than a list because you never iterate the values in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to realize that [`GetProperties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb(v=vs.110).aspx) is called *not* on the object itself, but rather its `Type`.  The method returns an array of [`PropertyInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) objects, which only contain information about the definition of a property.

So your question effectively becomes "How can I use `PropertyInfo` to obtain the value of the property for a given object instance?", and the answer to that is quite simply "Call the [`PropertyInfo.GetValue(Object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

See below for an example:

```
public Dictionary<String, String> GetPropertyValues<T>(T obj)
{
    Dictionary<String, String> result = new Dictionary<String, String>();
    var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        String name = property.Name;
        String value = property.GetValue(obj).ToString();
        result.Add(name, value);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass { PropertyName = "Testing 1, 2, 3" };

String template = "The value of PropertyName is '{PropertyName}'";
var replacements = GetPropertyValues(myClass);
foreach (var replacement in replacements)
{
    // Note that you have to double-up the '{' and '}' characters to escape them.
    String token = String.Format("{{{0}}}", replacement.Key);
    Console.WriteLine("Searching for occurrences of '{0}'", token);
    template = template.Replace(token, replacement.Value);
}

Console.WriteLine(template);
// Output:
// The value of PropertyName is 'Testing 1, 2, 3'
```

Class definition used in demonstration:

```
// A simple class definition for demonstration purposes.
// The method is generic, so as to work reasonably well for general purposes.
public class MyClass
{
    public String PropertyName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must use `prop.Name` to get the name of the property and `prop.GetValue(object obj)` to get the Value..

Source:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx